# composer.json file not updating when plugins are updated

Tags: plugins, composer

My composer.json file doesn't update to the latest plugin versions when I update my plugins via the Craft CP or command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a caret icon infront of your version number, for example

```
"craftcms/cms": "^3.0.0",
```

These version numbers in `composer.json` will not change when you update.

The caret icon tells Composer it has free reign to update this package, but not to the next major version number. `^3.0.0` can update to `3.1.0`, `3.2.0`, `3.2.1` etc, but won't update to `4.0.0`. As such, it does not need to write to `composer.json` because the caret icon is already giving it the instructions it needs.

You can read more about it in the [Composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#caret-version-range-).

Running `composer update` will (if there are updates to perform) write to `composer.lock` instead. If you are using version control, you can run a `git diff` to see what changes have been made to your lock file immediately after running an update.